# Angular binding within binding

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm in the process of refactoring some code written with Angular.js, mostly as an attempt to prevent the braces from rendering whilst everything loads. The original code looks like:

```
<p class="summary">{{ feature.articleSummary }}<a ng-href="/feature/reader/?articleId={{feature.articleId}}" class="summary">...(more)</a></p>
```

And then attempted refactoring to:

```
<p class="summary" ng-bind="feature.articleSummary"><a ng-href="/feature/reader/?articleId={{feature.articleId}}" class="summary">...(more)</a></p>
```

However, this loses the embedded `<a>` element. Is it possible to bind an element within a binding? Or would it be better to create a directive to handle a new template? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first use `ng-bind-html` instead of the simple `ng-bind` and then you should create a filter so sanitise the html:

```
yourApp.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

So that your code goes like this:

```
<p class="summary" ng-bind-html="feature.articleSummary | sanitize">...</p>
```